# single-product.php template not working for single products

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, templates

`single-product.php` template not working for my Woo commerce single products and instead it is using `single.php` file of my theme. I do not have `woocommerce.php` file in my theme but still `single-product.php` not executing.
Any idea about this will be much appreciated.

Comment: You have it in 'yourtheme'/woocommerce/single-product.php (notice the lack of capital letters)?

Comment: I add this line to my theme functions.php and now everything working fine. add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );

Comment: Thank you. Adding add_theme_support('woocommerce') to functions is what fixed this problem for me, too.

Comment: Note that, when you add add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );, it must be outside of any function call.  Aka, you cannot put it in the add_support function and call that function from add_action('init', 'add_support');

Comment: Best answer will be create singe-product.php file in your theme folder.
And write this code <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' ); ?>

Comment: @kloddant Not how WooCommerce showed in their github though. https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Declaring-WooCommerce-support-in-themes