# Woocommerce template single-product.php in theme folder not working

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, templates

`single-product.php` not working for single products. I do not have `woocommerce.php` file in my theme but still `single.php` executing for single products.
This is a custom theme and when i change my theme name to `twentyten` then `single-product.php` started to execute but when i change its name to something else (custom theme name) than this template does not work at all and instead it execute single.php
Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you posting this again? It's been less than a day. Besides, it's about a 3rd-party plugin and off-topic. Please see the WooCommerce [developer documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-theme-developer-handbook/) for supporting WooCommerce in your theme.

Comment: I was not able to get any response on this issue that is why i post this again. If this is off-topic then why woocommerce tag is available ?

Comment: Firstly, 15 hours is not enough time to say you didn't get a response. Secondly, when you select WooCommerce as a tag a box literally appears right under it that says "OFF TOPIC. Questions *specific* for this e-commerce plugin have their own forum at https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce.".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [single-product.php template not working for single products](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/298634/single-product-php-template-not-working-for-single-products)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I add this line in my theme's functions.php file and now everything working fine.

```
add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
```